# Firestore printing multiple instances of single document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Trying to print all documents in a subcollection (userRecipes)

[image]

I only have two documents present in the subcollection - Issue is when I print to console, It's printing the two documents multiple times in excess. Example of the prints below:

> ["Flounder": {
> createdAt = "<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1656102838 nanoseconds=66710000>";
> directions =     (
> Example
> );
> ingredientItem =     {
> Example = Example;
> };
> recipeImage = "";
> recipePrepTime = "";
> recipeTitle = Flounder; }]] [["eggs": {
> createdAt = "<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1656102790 nanoseconds=482897000>";
> directions =     (
> );
> ingredientItem =     {
> "1 cup" = Flour;
> };
> recipeImage = "";
> recipePrepTime = "20 Mins";
> recipeTitle = eggs; }]] [["eggs": {
> createdAt = "<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1656102790 nanoseconds=482897000>";
> directions =     (
> );
> ingredientItem =     {
> "1 cup" = Flour;
> };
> recipeImage = "";
> recipePrepTime = "20 Mins";
> recipeTitle = eggs; }], ["Flounder": {
> createdAt = "<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1656102838 nanoseconds=66710000>";
> directions =     (
> Example
> );
> ingredientItem =     {
> Example = Example;
> };
> recipeImage = "";
> recipePrepTime = "";
> recipeTitle = Flounder; }]]

Below is my code:

```
class RecipeLogic: ObservableObject {
    @Published var recipes = [RecipeItems]()
    @Published var recipeList = []
    init(){
     grabRecipes()
    }
    
    private func grabRecipes(){
        
        
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
            .collection("users")
            .document(uid)
            .collection("userRecipes")
            .getDocuments() { (snapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("error")
                }
                else{
                    for recipe in snapshot!.documents {
                        self.recipeList.append(recipe.data())
                        print(self.recipeList)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

struct RecipeItems: Codable, Hashable{
    var recipeTitle, recipePrepTime, recipeImage, createdAt: String
    var directions, ingredientItem: [String]
}

struct RecipeModel:Codable, Identifiable {
   var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var recipes: [RecipeItems]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Probably your RecipeLogic is created several times, set breakpoint to `grabRecipes()` in init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing `recipeList` on every iteration of your for loop, each time getting an updated version, to print the documents of Firebase just once, you do so by:

```
for recipe in snapshot!.documents {
      self.recipeList.append(recipe.data())
}
if let documents = snapshot.documents {
  // Your documents
  print(documents)
}
```

Comment: Hi - Thank you for your response, but unfortunately this doesn't help the issue, only because I have a single document in firestore so shouldn't the for loop only run once regardless? Also trying to amend each document to the arrray

Comment: @Swink your data will be appended to recipeList, but your documents will be printed in full, and once.

Comment: Hey apologies if I'm not fully comprehending this approach. The array works at grabbing the data. If I use let documents, it pulls just the screenshot of the doc. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot#/c:objc(cs)FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot(im)data              Just trying to store my firestore data in an array, that I can then call in another view